# DF is lost after JCOP restart?

Tags: eclipse, arrays, javacard, jcop

I am working on a small ticketing prototype.
What I want to do is - if the top-level ADF is selected I want to return the AID of all the containing DFs and on first sight it works quite well.

I create the ADF, and 1 or 2 DFs. When the ADF is selected, the AIDs of those DFs are returned fine and I can add EFs (or DFs), ...

Now when I restart the whole thing (I am using JCOP btw.) I can still select the ADF but the AIDs from the DFs are not returned anymore, in fact I get a 6F00 "no precise diagnosis".

For my data structure - first you see the minimal constructor for the ADF, which has no parents

```
public DirectoryFile(byte[] aid) {
  super(aid);
  this.aid = aid;
  numApp = 1;
  created = true;
}
```

the second structure is the same but for a "usual" DirectoryFile with a parentDirectoryFile and an array (arrayFiles) of Elementary Files:

```
public DirectoryFile(byte[] aid, DirectoryFile parent) {
    super(aid, parent);
    for (byte i = 0; i < numberFiles; i++) {
      arrayFiles[i].setActive(false);
    }   
}
```

both inherit from the same File.class

```
public File (byte aid[]) {
    Util.arrayCopy(aid, (short) 0, this.aid, (short) 0, (short) 6); 
}

public File (byte[] aid, DirectoryFile parentFile) {
    this.parentFile = parentFile;
    Util.arrayCopy(aid, (short) 0, this.aid, (short) 0, (short) 6); 
}
```

This should be a very basic Filesystem and it does work as long as the card is connected to the terminal, but the information seems to be lost after restart of the program although I am not using transient arrays at all for this.

The return code is always "6F00 - no precise diagnosis" which leads to an unreferred byte[] or something like that, which I cannot find any except of the DF objects, that get instanciated when the new Object is created.

EDIT: just figured out it might be a more "general" problem and that is what I am doing wrong.

Now, if I take a "Hello World" like http://umer555.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/java-card-hello-world-applet/ and add some INS like I did here:

```
  public class HalloWeltApplet extends Applet {
    private static byte[] helloWorld = new byte[11];
    private static final byte HW_CLA = (byte)0x80;
    private static final byte HW_INS = (byte)0x00;
    private static final byte HW_INS1 = (byte)0x01;
    private static final byte HW_INS2 = (byte)0x02;


    public static void install(byte[] bArray, short bOffset, byte bLength) {
      new HalloWeltApplet().register(bArray, (short) (bOffset + 1), bArray[bOffset]);
    }

   public void process(APDU apdu) {
     if (selectingApplet()) {
       return;
     }

     byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
     byte CLA = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_CLA] & 0xFF);
     byte INS = (byte) (buffer[ISO7816.OFFSET_INS] & 0xFF);

     if(CLA != HW_CLA) {
       ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_CLA_NOT_SUPPORTED);
     }

     switch(INS) {
       case HW_INS:
         getHelloWorld(apdu);
         break;
       case HW_INS1:
         getHelloWorld1(apdu);
         break;
       case HW_INS2:
         getHelloWorld2(apdu);
         break;
       default:
         ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INS_NOT_SUPPORTED);
      }

   }

   private void getHelloWorld( APDU apdu) {
     byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
     short length = (short) helloWorld.length;
     byte[] test =  {(byte)'H',(byte)'e',(byte)'l',(byte)'l',(byte)'o',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d',};

     Util.arrayCopy(test, (short) 0, helloWorld, (short) 0, (short) test.length);

   }  
   private void getHelloWorld1( APDU apdu) {
     byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
     short length = (short) helloWorld.length;
     byte[] test =  {(byte)'H',(byte)'i',(byte)' ',(byte)'W',(byte)'o',(byte)'r',(byte)'l',(byte)'d'};

     Util.arrayCopy(test, (short) 0, helloWorld, (short) 0, (short) test.length);

   }
   private void getHelloWorld2( APDU apdu) {
     byte[] buffer = apdu.getBuffer();
     apdu.setOutgoing();
     apdu.setOutgoingLength((short) helloWorld.length);
     apdu.sendBytesLong(helloWorld, (short) 0, (short) helloWorld.length);
   }
 }
```

So this should in my eyes save 'Hello World' or 'Hi World' into `helloWorld` and with INS2 I can show which one is saved. But whenever I restart the program, `helloWorld` will be empty due to initiation, right? Could that be my problem after all, and if so, how can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably here:

```
super(aid);
this.aid = aid;
```

First you correctly copy the data, then you overwrite the field in `File` with the one you've used in the `DirectoryFile` constructor. If that is a transient buffer or worse, the JCRE owned APDU buffer, then your code will fail as JCRE owned objects should not be used through persistent references.

Note that AID's are *Application* Identifiers. They identify applications such as your Java Card applet. Normally files and non-application DF's (especially child DF's) are not identified or selected with an AID but with a file identifier or a (related) short file identifier. See ISO/IEC 7816-4 (any version I guess) for details.

Note that resets work in the JCOP simulator, but that all information is lost when you restart the process; data is not saved to disk and applets must be reloaded.

Comment: I figured that the aid in the `DirectoryFile` constructor is not in use after all, so I left it out completely. Won't make a difference though.

@AID's - I am aware of that, but I have "kind of" a master ADF and only slave ADFs which should be the applications, hence I am using the AIDs, and not the file IDs.

Comment: Anytime I restart the HelloWorld-Example and "print" content of `helloWorld` it returns an empty Array?

Comment: Don't write to static byte arrays, remove the `static` keyword. Static is tricky in Javacard.

Comment: that is true, but won't make a change

Comment: i dont see anything suspicous. try copying the array onto the apduBuffer and use apdu.setOutgoingandSend instead

Comment: that works of course while I am executing the program. But shouldn't it be the case that, on persistent memory, this should be saved on the card and stay there - so the contents should stay there?
or is just my mind already flying away?

Comment: Adjusted answer for JCOP sim.

Comment: so, if I get you correctly - I start the JCOP shell and select the applet and then the card should work correctly until resetted? So, in that way my adressing, saving data would be correct.

I am using a "Masteroperator-Class", a "Point-of-sale"-Class and a "AcessGate"-Class ... the main problem: If I put the card off the reader and back on, I cannot access the data anymore - is that due to the used hardware (card reader) + JCOP Shell and is quite normal or is it my fault?

Comment: No, the JCOP software *simulator* does not save memory between processes; if you restart the sim, you loose all your data. A normal card should not forget *persistent* (EEPROM/flash) data unless specified differently by the Java Card RE & API. Transient data and JCRE owned objects (notably the APDU buffer) are however likely to be cleared at certain times (after process, a deselect or reset). Note that a deselect takes place whenever an AID is found that can be selected during SELECT by AID, without regard of Applet state (!). This includes the (possibly shortened) AID of the applet itself.

Comment: I am not working with a simulator, but a JCOP card/card reader. So this must be my fault and the persistent data should stay on card - I should hereby always be able to select by AID, read/write EFs and such!
So, when my "Masteroperator" instantiates the card and a ticket is bought at the PoS the gate should get the information if a card is "there" and correct... always!

Comment: because at the moment, it is not! the gate will return 6f00 after i take the card off/back on

Comment: `6F00` is an unhandled exception at the end of the process() method usually. All JC exceptions are runtime exceptions, but you should surround "suspicious" code with try/catch and handle the exceptions (e.g. `ISOException.throwIt(better status word)`).

Comment: in my processSelect I call the DF with `df = adf.getDF(selectedAID);`
and this is not returning a DF.
So the DF information is either lost or not linked after putting away the card anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54924/discussion-between-owlstead-and-achiever).